# Converting complex C Typedef statements to Delphi Records

Tags: c, delphi

For the use of a DLL I have only the C Header Files available. Now I am converting these header files to Delphi Interface Files. That works quite well till there occur complex C Typedef like this one:

```
  typedef struct _IFSDK_PAUSE
  {
    int version;
    FPDF_BOOL (*NeedToPauseNow) (struct _IFSDK_PAUSE* pThis);
    void*       user;
  } IFSDK_PAUSE;
```

that converts to:

```
type
  IFSDK_PAUSE = record

    version: Integer;

    pThis: <----- Problem!!!

    user: Pointer;
  end
```

How do I convert these complex Typedefs correctly?

Comment: This is pointer to function which returns `FPDF_BOOL` and has one parameter of type `struct _IFSDK_PAUSE*`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's a function pointer. It receives a pointer to the struct, and returns a `FPDF_BOOL`. Presumably, since there is no calling convention specified, the default calling convention of `cdecl` applies.

With that information, you would translate to Delphi like this:

```
type
  PIFSDK_PAUSE = ^IFSDK_PAUSE;
  TNeedToPauseNow = function(pThis: PIFSDK_PAUSE): FPDF_BOOL; cdecl;
  IFSDK_PAUSE = record
    version: Integer;
    NeedToPauseNow: TNeedToPauseNow;
    user: Pointer;
  end;
```

Note that unlike C, a Delphi procedural type is implicitly a pointer.